# Exporting mileage between a route

Tags: network-analyst, route

I am working on a project where I need to find the mileage between an inspector's daily stops. I have a route of 11 stops and am having trouble figuring out if its possible to export out the mileage between stops but not the cumulative mileage

Comment: Can you edit the question or the tags to show what software and version you are using? It sounds like ArcGIS? I'm no network expert but a quick work around might be to break up the stops into separate routs. So instead of 1 route with 11 stops you can have 11 routs and just export the rout mileage.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to solve this in Network Analyst.  Once you create your network dataset and select Vehicle Routing Problem.  Load your depot and your stops (orders) into it and then solve click solve network.  This will solve your routes for you,  The right click ORDERS from the TOC and select open attributes, in the attribute table you will see many fields, the one you want is:

***FromPrevDistance:*** The travel distance from the preceding visit on the route to the order. The unit for the travel distance is specified by the Distance Field Units property of the analysis layer. This field is null if the Distance Attribute property is not specified in analysis parameters.

[image]

Here is a tutorial that helps explain: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Solving_a_vehicle_routing_problem

and

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Solving_a_vehicle_routing_problem